# Stop executing last print statement in case of division with b is zero

Tags: java

hii     When i execute the division thing and enter b as zero.. i just want it to show operation not possible message and not print the result.. which any case will be 0.. how can i avoid it?

I just want to know how can i dismiss the last print statement in case of division when b=o

```
import java.util.*;

public class calculator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner stack = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("We can do the following operations"); // my choices of operation
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3. Mutliply");
        System.out.println("4. division");

        System.out.println("Enter your choice of operation");

        int i = stack.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter first number");
        int a = stack.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter second number");
        int b = stack.nextInt();

        double result = 0;

        switch (i) {
        case 1:
            result = a + b;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = a - b;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = a * b;
            break;
        case 4:
            if (b == 0) {
                System.out.println("division not possible");
                break;
            } else

                result = a % b;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("go to hell");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("The result is:" + result);
        stack.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println("go to hell");` +1

Comment: What about an `if (b != 0)` around the `println`?

Comment: Add a `if(!(i == 4 && b == 0))` before your print statement for result?

Answer (score 0):

you can try an if statement:

```
if(b == 0){

}else{
 System.out.println("The result is:" + result);
}
```

or even better:

```
if(b != 0){
  System.out.println("The result is:" + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use

```
case 4:
  if(b==0) {
    System.out.println("division not possible");
    result = 0; // <-- assign something.
    // System.exit(1); // <-- to just exit.
  } else { // <-- add brackets and else.
    result = a / b;
  }
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

1. Define a method e.g.

   public static void show(result) {
       System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
   }

and call it from all the switch cases except for the 4th one if b == 0.

3. Throw an exception in the division by zero case and catch it in the end.
4. Don't check the argument and catch the runtime exception thrown by the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the last print statement in case of division when`b=0`
    you just check if condition.

```
if(!(i == 4 && b == 0)){
 System.out.println("The result is:" +result);
}
```